# Why use the Kronecker product?

Tags: matrices, kronecker-product, vectorization

I have found many references on Kronecker product but I did not see any reference talking about why this way of multiplication exist and whats the intuitive use of this particular product.

Appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: According to wikipedia it generalizes the outer product to matrix from vectors. So it seems where ever you would use an outer product with vectors, generalizes the same principles to matrix or tensors. So vector fields to tensor fields.

Comment: If you can explain little more would be helpful. I did understand that this product generalizes vectors to tensorial form. To understand this do I need to know more about Tensors?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is often very useful when one is solving or optimizing a function where the unknown is a matrix. This is because of the following relationship between the Kronecker product $\otimes$ and the [vectorization operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) $\operatorname{vec}(\cdot)$ that takes a matrix and unwinds it into a long vector:
$$\operatorname{vec}(\underbrace{AXB}_{\text{matrices}}) = \underbrace{(B^T \otimes A)}_{\text{matrix}}\underbrace{\operatorname{vec}(X)}_\text{vector}$$
For example, if you want to solve the matrix equation
$$AXB + X = C,$$
you can convert it to the following linear system:
$$(B^T \otimes A + I)\operatorname{vec}(X) = \operatorname{vec}(C).$$
More generally, matrices have both multiplicative (operator) and additive (vector space) structures, and combination of Kronecker products and vectorization provide the algebraic framework for converting back and forth between these contexts.

Comment: This explanation makes sense could please explain why you used the Kronecker instead of simple matrix multiplication in the linear equation?

Comment: Consider the shapes of the objects. For example, if $X$ is a matrix of size $n$-by-$n$, then $\operatorname{vec}(X)$ is a vector of length $n^2$, and so any invertible matrix multiplying it must be very big, having size $n^2$-by-$n^2$, rather than $n$-by-$n$.

Comment: And oddity of MathJax appears: I changed \text{vec} to \operatorname{vec} with the expected result that context-dependent spacing before and after "vec" would go into effect, but some experiment reveals that when there's an underbrace with subscript text under it, then that doesn't work, but when there's an underbrace with no such subscript, then it works as expected. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I'm a bit unsure of how it is supposed to look, but perhaps the cause is an unusually large bounding box for the subscript text? For example, see here: https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=f51sef

Comment: @Nick Alger, Infact I just want to know why is this operation important why you want a bigger structure of matrix? I see it on many places people are employing Kronecker without explaining intuition behind, so why you want it to be of size $n^2\times n^2 $ matrix rather than  $n\times n. $

Comment: @Vendetta In the vectorized form with the bigger matrix, you can solve for $\text{vec}(X)$ by applying the inverse of the bigger matrix to the right hand side $\text{vec}(C)$. In the non-expanded form consisting of sandwiched matrix multiplications, it is not clear how to solve the system for $X$.

Answer (score 4):

The Kronecker product is relied on incessantly in the study of distribution of test statistics in ANOVA and design of experiments.  It is used constantly in a plethora of ways in the theory of the Wishart distribution. In those topics I am rusty.  I have also seen it used in biochemistry, but in that topic I never went through all the details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Wishart distribution does makes sense in context to Kronecker delta. The case of Multivariate Gamma function  is a generalization of Wishart distribution where each sample is independently drawn from p-normal variables  with zero mean. Its a  probability distribution of a covariance matrix $(n \geq p)$ with some degrees of freedom. So the multivariate statistics involve wishart for high dimensional analysis that leads us to Kronecker.